# How to simulate a "lock timeout" error with Django on MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm, database-locking

What's the easiest way to simulate a "lock timeout" DatabaseError with Django using the MySQL backend?

I have a piece of code, that operates over large querysets, and occasionally it throws the exception:

```
 DatabaseError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

I understand what causes this and how to fix it, but I'm not sure how to test my fix since the error only happens in a production environment where several users are accessing certain tables simultaneously.

I first tried to run [some sample code](http://shiningpanda.com/mysql-table-lock-django.html) in a separate process to make Django apply a lock in MySQL, and while it does seem to lock the target table and make all other requests wait, a lock timeout never occurs when I test on my localhost with runserver. I let it run for 20 minutes without a timeout occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to have an exception of specific type why not to mock/monkeypatch your code in test to throw this exeption instead of fetching from database?